# Finding the range of $|\sin (x)|+|\cos (x)|$ by considering each quadrant as a separate case

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I was given  homework on trigonometric range and here is the question that I was stuck in.

> Find the range of the function
> $$|\sin (x)|+|\cos (x)|$$

In my attempt I knew that it can be solved by taking $4$ cases of $4$ quadrants. But my answer doesn't match. My teacher tell me the solution by squaring.

I need a solution that involve taking cases. I am a beginner in trigonometry so please help.

Comment: Here's how you can write math formulas so they display well on this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You say you got an answer but it "didn't match". Step by step, show us how you got your answer. Someone then could confirm you are correct or show you where you went wrong. Also, what was the other answer that disagreed with yours?

Comment: I just make 4 cases, case 1 x ∈ [0 , π/2] case 2 x ∈ [π/2 , π] case 3 x ∈ [π , 3π/2] and case 4 x ∈ [3π/2 , 2π] in all 4 case cos(x) and sin(x) have different signs by applying astc rule I found different intervals and then take intersection of them. Is my way correct??

Comment: Show, don't tell. You showed your four cases, but you only told about the rest of the steps. Also, your work should be **in the question**, not in a comment below the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a geometric way to handle the four cases. It involves equations like Equation $(1)$ below:

$$ \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r. $$

If you set $r$ to some constant value and plot the solutions of Equation $(1)$ you get a figure like the one below, a square whose sides make $45$-degree angles with the axes:

[image]

This particular square is the graph of $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r$ where
$r = 4.$

The nice thing about this square is it represents four cases all at once.
The side in the first quadrant shows what the solutions of
$\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r$ are for $x > 0$ and $y > 0,$
the side in the second quadrant shows what the solutions are for $x < 0$ and $y > 0,$
and so forth for the third and fourth quadrants.

Now let's consider what happens if we plot the following parametric equations,
using the parameter $\theta$:

\begin{align}
x &= \cos(\theta), \\
y &= \sin(\theta).
\end{align}

We get a circle of radius $1$ with center at $(0,0),$ of course.
Now let's see what happens if we inscribe a square within the circle and circumscribe another square around the circle as shown in the figure below:

[image]

The squares are graphs of $\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r$
for two different constant values of $r.$

Note that the circle cannot touch the plot of
$\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r$ for any $r$ smaller than the
$r$ value used for the small square.
That is, you cannot have any smaller sum of
$\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert
 = \lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert + \lvert\sin(\theta)\rvert.$

The circle also cannot touch the plot of
$\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert = r$ for any $r$ larger than the
$r$ value used for the large square.
That is, you cannot have any larger sum of
$\lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert + \lvert\sin(\theta)\rvert.$

But the sum $\lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert + \lvert\sin(\theta)\rvert$ can be equal to the $r$ value of either square because the circle touches both squares.

So if you can just figure out what $r$ is for each of these squares, you have the smallest and largest possible values of
$\lvert\cos(\theta)\rvert + \lvert\sin(\theta)\rvert.$

These are also the smallest and largest values of
$\lvert\cos(x)\rvert + \lvert\sin(x)\rvert.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=|\sin x|+|\cos x|$ then the first thing we can say is that $f(x)>0$ and the second thing is that $f(x)<2$ since $|\sin|$ and $|\cos|$ are both between 0 and 1 and are never both equal to 0 or both equal to 1.

In the first quadrant, $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$, $|\sin x|=\sin x$ and $|\cos x|=\cos x$ so $f(x)=\sin x+\cos x$. You say your teacher got the answer by squaring, so let's do that.
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)^2&=\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2 x\\
&=1+2\sin x \cos x
\end{align}
$$
using $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$. Now use $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ to get
$$
f(x)^2=1+\sin 2 x
$$
So the maximum value this may attain is 2, when $2x=\pi/2$, and so $f(x)^2=2$ and $f(x)=\sqrt 2$, and the minimum is $f(x)^2=1$ when $x=0$ and so $\sin (2x)=0$, so $f(x)=\sqrt1=1$. So the minimum and maximum on the first quadrant are 1 and $\sqrt2$ respectively.

Hopefully you can fill this argument in with the values from the other quadrants.